# When updating to .NET Core 1.0 RC2 should "/Program Files/DNX/" be deleted?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

These instructions https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows indicate that all previous version of .NET Core should be removed from Windows via the Add/Remove Programs before installing .NET Core SDK 1.0 RC2 on Windows.

However after running the uninstall from Add/Remove Programs in Windows 7 and installing .NET Core SDK I see that my `/Program Files/DNX/` folder still exits.

[image: DNX Folder]

This makes me wonder if I should delete it to clean up the system.  But perhaps it's needed when working with older projects that were created with RC1 under DNX.

I'd like to know if it's ok to delete the dnx folder and it associated runtimes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's up to you. If you leave them there nothing bad will happen because the executables have different names (`dnx`/`dotnet`).

You can have dnx and dotnet side by side.

Answer (score 3):

You should not delete this folders if you have old (DNX-based) projects that you still want to run. Otherwise, you will need to reinstall the dnx runtimes again to work with your old (RC1) apps.

Your new (RC2, `dotnet cli`) projects will known nothing about this old dnx-based folder and will ignore it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft advise you to remove any old version of .Net Core. The DNX was the runtime and toolset used to build .Net Core and .Net Core apps as per Microsoft. It was consisted of DNVM, DNX and DNU.

With the .Net Core CLI all above (DNVM, DNX and DNU) are part of a single toolset.

You'll may find some issues when removing DNX, also when migrating a existing solution on any beta/rc version of clr or coreclr which were (dnxcore50 or dnx46) and [others](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#deprecated-monikers) deprecated now.

> NOTE: when uninstalling MS ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1 (old version), you
>   may have issues on your VS 2015 regarding to some projects templates,
>   existing MVC or WebAPI projects may not load.

I'd suggest you to migrate to .Net Core 1.0 as I did in my side, it was a little pain but you won't go anywhere with a project target to a deprecated version.

You can follow these links to migrate your app:

1) https://chsakell.com/2016/05/21/migrating-asp-net-5-rc1-apps-to-asp-net-core/

2) http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html